# Facebook like button disable the count

Tags: facebook

I added face book like button on my site is there any way to disabled the count which is display next to the button.

http://www.knowledgenotebook.com/FB/notShow.png

Comment: Can you at least post a screenshot or some code so we know what you're talking about? What does it count? How did you implement this? What language?

Comment: Added the screen shot what to not display.

Answer (score 8):

You can but not directly.

You have to set data-layout="box_count", wrap button code with extra element, set overflow and move button up. It will be something like that:

```
<style>
.fb-wrap {height:20px; overflow:hidden;}
.fb-wrap div {position:relative; top:-41px;}
</style>

<div class="fb-wrap"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mysite.com/" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-show-faces="false"></div></div>
```

This will work more bulletproof than crop by width because of internationalization

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, honestly I'm very disappointed that Facebook still didn't do anything to make the button configuration easier (show/hide count, change size, etc.). All the other mayor social buttons - Twitter, G+, LinkedIn, Pinterest have this option available, and there's no need to make CSS workarounds which not always work (mentioned above case of different languages).

Answer (score 1):

For simple sites, just add a fixed width to the `iframe` ( `width:47px !important;` )
For the multilingual sites where you have to display the Like/Recommend text in more than one language (EN: Recommend, DE: Empfehlen) the text length is different and you can't set a fixed width, but you can use `layout=box_count` and set a fixed height:

```
height: 70px; margin-top:-41px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

The count is not a configurable attribute

Comment: You can. You can't do it on Facebook's site, but it is totally possible to hide the count.

Answer (score 0):

You can. All you need to do is set the width to 47 in facebook's iframe code.

Comment: What about different languages? The like button is localized. In Germany the label is set to "Gefällt mir". 47 pixels won't work here and there are quite a lot of other languages.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers for the different cases where you can hide the count in the answers here:

[Facebook Like-Button - hide count?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count)

The side effect is that you have to hide the comment flyout as well.

Answer (score 0):

The default attributes you have available are here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

The code loads an iFrame on your site and you maybe able to adjust the size of the iFrame to hide certain components based on the design "Layout Style" you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it using css styles, adjusting the width and hiding overflow, but be aware it's forbidden.

[Facebook Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) 
IV. Application Integration Points

4 d. You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a share and like button (and don't need internationalization) this works:

```
<style>
    .fb-wrap {height:20px; overflow:hidden;}
    .fb-wrap div {position:relative; left: 27px; margin-left: -27px;}
</style>
<div class="fb-wrap">
    <div class="fb-like" 
         data-width="160"
         data-layout="button_count"
         data-show-faces="false" 
         data-send="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was change data-layout attribute from "box-count" to "button". Worked fine.

```
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href=@longURL data-layout="button">
```